# По проекции правильной пирамиды на определить на какой угол она была повернута

Tags: python, математика

```
    Sample Input:

430
192 567
83 371
81 688
333 380
334 698
```

Comment: Пирамида правильная?

Comment: Поворот происходит только в одной плоскости?

Comment: "Нужно получить угол поворота пирамиды относительно оси, проходившей до поворота через вершину пирамиды и центр квадрата ее основания." - это значит, что пирамиду вращали строго вертикально? тогда проекция вершины всегда будет лежать на пересечении диагоналей квадрата основания.

Comment: Ну то есть в условии задачи подразумевается, что основанием пирамиды является квадрат. Почему это не указано явно?

Comment: Что за координаты даны в условии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее, как-то так должно работать:

1. У нас есть проекции четырёх вершин основания. Мы можем найти точку пересечения диагоналей.
2. Вычисляем расстояние между найденной точкой и проекцией вершины. Это расстояние является катетом, противолежащим искомому углу, в прямоугольном треугольнике, гипотенуза которого - высота пирамиды.
3. Следовательно, `искомый угол = арксинус(найденный_катет/высота_пирамиды)`

Comment: Спасибо, все верно!

Comment: @overfitt: Решение, разумеется, совершенно неправильное. Вышеприведенные утверждения верно только в том случае, если пирамида отклонялась от вертикального положения строго "по направлению к данному углу основания" (выряжаясь неформально). Выражаясь более форимально: толок в том случае, если плоскость, содержащая исходное положение высоты и финальное положение высоты, проходит через данный угол.  Для любых других отклонений ничего подобного не будет иметь места.

Comment: @AnT, что-то я не очень понял, что вы имеете в виду. Можете на цифрах привести пример, на котором мой алгоритм будет давать неверный результат?

Comment: Ну возьмем экстремальный пример: возьмите произвольную пирамиду и отклоните ее на 90 градусов **вокруг одной из сторон основания**, т.е. положите горизонтально. (Проекция основания выродится в отрезок, длина которого будет равна исходной длине стороны основания.)  Что теперь скажет ваш алгоритм?

Comment: @AnT, 90 градусов

Comment: Это как это? Пусть сторона основания равна `a`, в высота `h`. На шаге 2 вашего алгоритма мы получаем `a/2` - расстояние от центра проекции до любой из вершин проекции. На шаге 3 получаем `arcsin((a/2) / h)`. Где тут 90 градусов?

Comment: @AnT, на втором шаге получится h.

Comment: @Ant, там расстояние до проекции вершины пирамиды. А не вершины основания.

Comment: А, извините, неправильно прочитал алгоритм. Проекция вершины - тогда все верно. Непонятно только, что нам дано. Я почему-то считал, что нам дана именно проекция основания и под "вершиной" вы имеете в виду одну из вершин основания.

Comment: @AnT, там 5 точек - основание и вершина. Автор вопроса зачем-то убрал из вопроса пояснения.